# User Relationship Schema

Tags: objective-c, database-design, schema

I have a user relationship schema where User A can request a relationship with User B and structured as below:

```
User A | User B | Accepted
Bob    | Joe    | YES
John   | Tina   | undefined
Tina   | Mark   | NO
```

**YES** means that the person accepts the relationship. **Undefined** means that there hasn't been any action. **NO** means the relationship has been rejected.

In a typical scenario, when **User A** requests relationship with **User B**, I do a query to check if **User B** has already requested a relationship with **User A**, and if not then I add an entry. If yes, then I simply confirm the relationship and change accepted to **YES**.

My problem lies in if two users simultaneously request relationships to each other, then I end up with corrupt data.

Is there a better way to structure this schema?

Answer (score 0):

I think that would be more appreciated if you separate `Relation-Request` and `Relation` tables.
An accepted relation-request will become a relation, the relation may be canceled over time, in the current design you will lose the relation history.
The separation of concepts will also solve simultaneous request problem.
[image]